# How to exclude files from ubdatedb?

Tags: cron, locate, umount, updatedb

Yesterday, while trying to unmount our ([davfs2](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/davfs2) mounted) work webdav server from my filesystem, I got `device is busy`.

Running `sudo lsof | grep /mountpoint/of/davfs`, revealed that the culprit was `updatedb`. Running [`man updatedb`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/updatedb) revealed that this is a command run to update a database for mlocate, most probably invoked by cron.

While I sometimes use locate, i don't need it to include all files on our work server (we got other search tools for that), and I definitely do not want this to interfere with me unmounting the filesystem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you looked at `man updatedb.conf`? It seems possible that editing `/etc/updatedb.conf` may help control what is scanned. This is what my `/etc/updatedb.conf` looks like:

```
PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="yes"
# PRUNENAMES=".git .bzr .hg .svn"
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media /home/.ecryptfs /var/lib/schroot"
PRUNEFS="NFS nfs nfs4 rpc_pipefs afs binfmt_misc proc smbfs autofs iso9660 ncpfs coda devpts ftpfs devfs mfs shfs sysfs cifs lustre tmpfs usbfs udf fuse.glusterfs fuse.sshfs curlftpfs ecryptfs fusesmb devtmpfs"
```

From `man updatedb.conf`:

> PRUNENAMES A whitespace-separated list of directory names (without
>   paths) which should not be scanned by updatedb